# Minitest: How to test a method

Tags: ruby, sinatra, minitest

I'm trying to test the method in my code, but the second test is returning the error `undefined local variable or method 'params'`

What's the correct way to test the method? or is there a change i need to make to how the `main.rb` is set up?

code:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/reloader'


def get_products_of_all_ints_except_at_index()
  @array = [1, 7, 3, 4]
  @total = 1
  @index = params[:index].to_i
  @array.delete_at(@index)
  @array.each do |i|
    @total *= i
  end
end



get '/' do
  get_products_of_all_ints_except_at_index
  erb :home
end
```

test:

```
ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'

require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'rack/test'

require_relative 'main.rb'

include Rack::Test::Methods

def app
  Sinatra::Application
end

describe 'app' do
  it 'should return something' do
    get '/'
    assert_equal(200, last_response.status)
  end

  it 'should return correct result' do
    get_products_of_all_ints_except_at_index
    assert_equal(24, @total)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't passing any params with your get request, try:

```
get '/', :index => '1'
```

Comment: This should help out: http://www.sinatrarb.com/testing.html
All mock request methods have the same argument signature:

get '/path', params={}, rack_env={}

Answer (score 0):

Tthe first test works since there is a default `params` map setup for you when calling `get '/'`. But when you call the method directly `params` is `nil` and that is why you get the error. The best way here is to send in the data you need to you method. Something like:

```
def get_products_of_all_ints_except_at_index index
  @array = [1, 7, 3, 4]
  @total = 1
  @array.delete_at(index)
  @array.each do |i|
    @total *= i
  end
end

get '/' do
  get_products_of_all_ints_except_at_index params[:index].to_i
  erb :home
end
```

Finding things in the request is normally good to do in the outermost layer in the code. Then you *business code* will get higher testability also!